# where to define selector document.querySelector in LitElement?

Tags: javascript, dom, frontend, polymer, lit-element

A selector class is defined in css:

```
static get styles() {
    return css`
      .selector select {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 2rem 0 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  ...
}
```

I'm trying to add the following two lines into my LitElement:

```
export class MyPattern extends LitElement { 
... 
selector = document.querySelector(".selector select"); 
selector.addEventListener("input", triage); 
...
```

However no matter where I put them in the class definition, there is the exception:

```
*my-pattern.js:150 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null*
```

If it is possible to add such an event listener in an extended LitElement, where should they be written in an element class?

Comment: Are you trying to add the event listener to the current element or some other element?

Comment: I'm trying to add it to `class MyPattern extends LitElement`, namely the current element. Are there any succesful examples as reference for me? Those on the documentation site of LitElement don't help me much.

Answer (score 1):

In a LitElement your template is rendered in shadow DOM - the methods on `document` can only find light DOM elements (in the root document context).

To get the elements in your LitElement you need to access the shadow root:

```
selector = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".selector select");
```

Note that this will only find your element if both `.selector` and the `<select>` it contains are *both* inside your element.

Lit includes a [`query` decorator](https://lit.dev/docs/api/decorators/#query) to help with this:

```
@query('.selector select') selector: HTMLSelectElement;
...
this.selector.addEventListener("input", triage);
```

However, Lit gives you a much better way to hook up your events:

```
render () {
    return html`
<div class="selector">
    <select @input=${this.triage}>...
    </select>
</div>`;
}

triage(e) {
    // this will refer to the MyPattern class, not the <select> control 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The styles defined in `styles` getter is only applicable for the shadowRoot of a web component.

The template(in render function) of your `MyPattern` component should be using the `.selector` class somewhere

Then you can query on the shadowroot of the component using the css selector

```
selector = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".selector select"); 
selector.addEventListener("input", triage);
```